# What's the fix for module _mysql: This Python has API version 1012, module _mysql has version 1013

Tags: python, mysql

If I try to use the shell I get this API conflict.

```
/home/username/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg-tmp/_mysql.so:6: RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module _mysql: This Python has API version 1012, module _mysql has version 1013.
```

I'm running:
Python 2.6
MySQL Server version: 5.0.77
MySQL_python-1.2.3c1

I tried unsuccessfully to update to a new version of MySQL-python.

**easy_install-2.6 -d ~/lib/python2.6 MySQL-python**

```
Searching for MySQL-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3c1
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
MySQL-python 1.2.3c1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /home/username/lib/python2.6/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python
```

How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means the `_mysql` module, part of `MySQLdb`, was built for a newer version of Python than it's being loaded into. API version 1013 is the one used by Python 2.5 and 2.6, and 1012 is the one used by Python 2.4. You don't say *how* you're using MySQLdb, but apparently it's being imported by Python 2.4.

Comment: Is this error dangerous? What's the solution, what to do?